# R write over only first few lines of a file

Tags: r, file, overwrite

Hi I want to do something that I thought should be simple but can't seem to find a way. I have some files I want to change something in the heading lines, given by a  key word. The lines I want to change are always in the first 20 lines, but not necessarily exactly the same line number.

So I want to read in the first 20 lines (which is easy), find and change my string (again easy) and then write over the top 20 lines of the file and keep the thousands of rows below without changing. I'm going to have to do this hundreds and hundreds of times thus why I don't want to read in the entire file and write it all.

I have created a very simplified example. WARNING I'm creating a file called Temp.txt in your current working directory if you run this.

```
#Create Dummy text file 
write.table(file = "Temp.txt", data.frame(Test = letters[1:26]), row.names = F, quote = F)
```

And then I can read in the lines and change

```
# read top 5 lines of text file (In real life I need to look at 20, but for examples sake 2)
TestHeader = readLines("Temp.txt", n = 5)
# Find and replace my search string
TestHeader[grepl("c",TestHeader)] <- "My New Line"

# <what to do here?> I want to only write over first 20 lines
```

Obviously I can read in the entire thing and change

```
TestHeader = readLines("Temp.txt")
TestHeader[grepl("c",TestHeader)] <- "My New Line"
writeLines(TestHeader, "Temp.txt")
```

But this would involve unnecessarily reading and writing thousands and thousands of lines.

Comment: File systems don’t really work this way. Files don’t really have lines, they just have bytes that tell your screen to go to a new line some times. You can’t really change the beginning of a file. It’s much easier to append to the end of a file. Some you are changing the length of the beginning of the file, everything else has to shift down.

Comment: *"reading and writing thousands and thousands of lines"* are often best done with tools that do that one thing *very well*. If you need to change the first line of a file, it would be far faster to write that one line with R to `newfile`, then use `tail -n +2 oldfile >> newfile` to append everything else after it. (If you are on windows, getting `tail.exe` is a little less-direct; for me, I find it installed in [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), not a foregone conclusion. With Rtools, you can do `sed -ne '2,$p' oldfile >> newfile` for the same effect.)